# How do I make the div dissapear after onclick nr 2?

Tags: javascript

I tried this but obv it didnt work. Im very new to JS, how do I do this?

```
 function test() {
                if(document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block'){
                    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
                }
                if(document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'){
                    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
                }
  }
```

Comment: try this one  document.getElementById('div1').hide();

Comment: Can you post a JS Fiddle? Also, If i'm not wrong, the = is an assignment operator and == verifies it.

Comment: @SatejS I couldnt even get the "block" to work in fiddle :S https://jsfiddle.net/7wfz63ue/1/

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be `=`, it should be `==` in JavaScript `if` condition and twice `if` condition always setting `style.display = 'block'`, so either use `else if` or simply `else`.

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block"></div>

function test() {
       if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

or

```
function test() {
       if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ops thanks. It didnt help tho. When I have == the "block" doesnt even get done. == is correct tho.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have (once corrected) will toggle visibility but won't make an element invisible on the 2nd time a user clicks on it.

I've set up a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nmbgzyp4/) that uses plain JavaScript in order to do what you're asking in the title of the question.

Let's assume that your HTML looks something like this, with a `DIV` that has a class name of "tester":

```
<div class="tester">This is a triumph.</div>
<p>I'm writing a note here; huge success</p>
```

One way of achieving this is to add a data element to the `DIV` to track the number of clicks and then, when the number of clicks hits two, we hide it. The code for that looks like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tester")[0].onclick = function(targ) {
    if(!targ.target.hasAttribute("data-click")) {
        targ.target.setAttribute("data-click",0);
    }
    var currClicks = +targ.target.getAttribute("data-click");
    if(currClicks==2){
        targ.target.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        targ.target.setAttribute("data-click", currClicks+1);
    }
};
```

Again, this will get you the functionality you asked about in your question but does not match your code sample as it doesn't really do what you want. If you need any more information on this feel free to ask, but I think this will get you what you're looking for.